# CSS3 Transitions instead of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some divs as follows.

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="page1 active">
            <p>Page1</p>
            <button id="btn-about">Page2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="page2">
            <p>Page2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The pages are hidden by default unless they have the active class. To display a new page, I remove all active classes within the div which has class main and then add the active class to the page I want, for e.g page 2.

With something like this

```
$("#btn-about").click(

    function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".main div").removeClass("active");
       $(".main .page-2").addClass("active");

    }

);
```

And then it becomes something like this:

```
<div class="page2 active">
    <p>Page2</p>
</div>
```

It works fine but now I want, using CSS3, to hide or show the pages with certain effects. Sliding Up, Sliding Down, Sliding Left, Sliding Right or Fades.

I am a newbie regarding CSS3 and would appreciate all the help.

Comment: Here are some examples for inspiration: http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS animations you can use the `transition:` style, for a sequence of transitions combine it with `transition-delay:`

Here are some good places to start researching:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

And this tutorial has the transitions you mentioned:

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/
- Demo: Sliding in from top (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index.html#home)
- Demo: Fading in/out (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index2.html#portfolio)
- Demo: Sliding in from side (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index3.html#portfolio)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at

- [Effeckt.css](https://github.com/h5bp/Effeckt.css), which is a great project from the html5-boilerplate team. But as they say  "Work in Progress! Not quite ready for prime-time"
- [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) which is more production ready but less ambitious